# Coordinate Location in Swift returning nil when authorized

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the current coordinates of a user based on their location in Swift.

I've imported

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
```

And I've created two global variables called

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation: CLLocation!
```

In my `viewDidLoad()` function, I have requested authorization from the user like this:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
        case .restricted, .denied, .notDetermined:
            print("not determined")
            return
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("authorized")
            currentLocation = locationManager.location
            print(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
            return
        default:
            print("default!")
        }
```

And in my [info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbSfF.png), I've added the location request description. However, when I run my application, it will print out `authorized` but when it tries to print the user location (the latitude, in this example). I get
`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`. Why am I getting this error if I've made sure the location manager was authorized? Thanks!

Comment: `var currentLocation: CLLocation!` is causing the error. You are force unwrapping a property that has a `nil` value. Before you do anything else, change it to `var currentLocation: CLLocation?` and then proceed to unwrap it safely (remember, it takes time to generate a location, it is not instant). However, to use location in the way you want I would recommend setting up the location manager environment in a place like the app delegate (as early as possible in the lifecycle of the process).

Comment: Liquid, you should post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: Thank you liquid, this seems to have solved it